# Remove index.php from codeigniter in xamp

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I've tried quite a few answers but keep coming up against the good ol, 404 wall of terror. I'm on Windows 7 using a xamp stack. mod_rewrite is enabled.

I put the htaccess file in the main "codeigniter" directory, that is, the directory with application, system and user_guide. Should I put it under the application directory instead? The one with the views/model/config/etc.?

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /website/codeigniter/

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Accessing http://localhost/website/codeigniter/index.php/welcome works
Accessing http://localhost/website/codeigniter/welcome does not

My config.php has

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/website/codeigniter/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

The error is:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Error 404
```

**UPDATE**
Oh, just thought about looking in apache logs, getting this error:

```
[Thu Mar 08 18:28:25 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/website/codeigniter/welcome
```

So it appears not to be picking up the proper codeigniter redirection? Not sure?

Answer (score 5):

first create .htacess file and paste below code in that
RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

then go to config file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and enjoy

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

have you enabled the mod_rewrite in apache?

Comment: why comment on a 2 years old answer? I already marked it for delete

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error again and again but after little research, I found a solution.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Codeigniter_start/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Codeigniter_start/index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>
```

The important point is, `the project folder`. Like I use `RewriteBase /Codeigniter_start/` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Codeigniter_start/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`.

Also change from config file index_page like this.

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line of your htaccess to:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try changing your request method in your config file from `AUTO` to `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, enable "rewrite module' of apache in XAMPP

If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file at:

```
{xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Find following line and remove the ‘#’ sign.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Actually, we can do upper by XAMPP popup menu: Apache -> Apache Modules -> rewrite module, and select it so as to enable it.

Secondly, we need change the htaccess by following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```