# How can i route to a controller and function in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need to route for example to "www.url.com/controller/function" i put the code in 'config.php' in routes but, doesn't work. i need to load to views in the same controller, without put 'index.php' in the url. It is possible?

Comment: what is your actual question ? Do you want to remove index.php from url ?

Comment: @Hameed i will take your advice. And really i want to show to different views without put index.php/controller

Answer (score 0):

here is the helping url to remove the index.php from url

[User Guide remove index.php](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

you have to use **.htaccess** file to remove index.php from url

Hope it helps

**Updated**

Have a look in the application\config\config.php file, there is a variable named 'index_page'

It should look like this

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

change it to

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

here is the .htaccess file you can use this..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Here are some use full links.. you can follow these..**

[remove index.php stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)
[remove index.php codeigniter forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/155801/)
[Enable mod rewrite from your server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619831/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-xamp)

Hope these will help you

Comment: actually i need to show to different views without putting index.php/controller/ when i do that, all the sources doesn't load.

Comment: @MrSanders: Dear i have update my answer. see it and hope now you will get rid from index.php

Answer (score 0):

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:

`www.url.com/index.php/controller/function`

You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Put the .htaccess file containing the above code to your app root folder.