# I cannot remove index.php from URL for Codeinator

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know this question have more answer on this page. But It is not work fine for me. I don't know why. I followed step by step as instruction. Could you please help me check.
Thanks for your support
The URL looks liks is : examplemysite.com

The link work well if I add index.php for it.

1. Change config.php -> $config['index_page'] = '';
2. $config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';
3. htaccess is located same level with index.php[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHSh3.png)

The content of htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled in your PHP?

Comment: are you running windows or linux as a web server for your app?

Comment: Hi @Phiter: Please suggest me how to check.

Comment: @unixmiah: I am running on windows

Comment: @KinQuang if you're running Apache, open your httpd.conf file and uncomment #LoadModule rewrite_modules/mod_rewrite.so then you need to add AllOverride All in your httpd.conf file. After you've done that restart Apache.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619831/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-xamp/51351995#51351995
Check this url and read my answer may be that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In to enable mod_rewrite for Windows and Linux, do the following:

**Windows:**

- Find and open the file .http.conf. This will be located in your Apache install folder.
- Make a backup of http.conf which you can restore from, if anything were to go wrong
- Find the line #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and remove the hash ‘#’enable-mod-rewrite-1
- Locate the block within the directory tags as indicated below and change to:

  Options All
  AllowOverride All
- Finally, restart apache server and your browser. The .htaccess rewriting should now be working.

**Linux (Ubuntu as an example):**

- Activate the mod_rewrite module with

  sudo a2enmod rewrite

and restart the apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To use mod_rewrite from within .htaccess files edit the virtualhost

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Below “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” add the following lines:

```
<Directory “/var/www/html”>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart the server again:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```