# Codeigniter remove index.php from cloudacropolis server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to remove `index.php` from codeigniter url. This code work for in every codeigniter site with `aws server`. But this time I am using cloudacropolis hosting and its not working for me. Here is the `.htaccess` code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ProjectEye/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Please see this if you don't get you may ask for guidance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619831/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-xamp/51351995#51351995